# Integration of $\int \frac{1}{x^{1/3}(x^{1/3}-1)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate the following function $$\int \frac{1}{x^{1/3}(x^{1/3}-1)}dx$$

Could someone give me slight hint to solve this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

Enforce the substitution $x=y^3$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Enforcing the substitution $x=y^3$ yields$$\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{x^{1/3}(x^{1/3}-1)}\,dx&=3\int \frac{y}{y-1}\,dy\\\\&=3\left(x^{1/3}+\log\left(\left|x^{1/3}-1\right|\right)\right)+C\end{align}$$